# Django ManyToMany Queryset AND instead of OR

Tags: django

I have the following query:

```
things = Thing.objects.filter(tags__in=selected_tags).distinct()
```

If selected_tags looks like this:

```
selected_tags = [<Tag: tag1>, <Tag: tag2>]
```

then things will contain any Thing that has tag1 OR tag2.

I want a query that gives me things that have tag1 AND tag2 (and maybe even tag3, but not necessarily).  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__in` is inherently OR-based. It literally says pull out any row that has any one of these tags. To create an AND based query, you'd need to filter for each tag individually:

```
Thing.objects.filter(tags=tag1, tags=tag2, ...)
```

That's obviously not ideal, and unfortunately, you can't even use an expanded dictionary in this scenario because all of the key's would be same. So your only other option is to use `Q`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = None
for tag in tags:
    if query is None:
        query = Q(tags=tag)
    else:
        query &= Q(tags=tag)

things = Thing.objects.filter(query)
```

It's a bit convuluted, but if you need to dynamically create the query (instead of just hardcoding each tag you're searching for), then it's your best bet.